# MySQL INSERT using SELECT with field that increments with each inserted row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with columns that look like this:

Table_1: 
`key | value
1   | apple
2   | banana
3   | carrot`

Table_2:
`sub_index | value`

Using a stored procedure, I want to insert rows from Table_1 into Table_2 using INSERT...SELECT such that for every time I execute the query, `sub_index` starts from 1.

For example, after I first run the query 
`INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (value) SELECT value FROM TABLE_1 WHERE key=2`

Table_2 should look like this:

`sub_index | value
1         | banana`

and then if I run another query

`INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (value) SELECT value FROM TABLE_1 WHERE key < 4`

Table_2 will now look like this:

`sub_index | value
1         | banana
1         | apple
2         | banana
3         | carrot`

and if I run a further query

`INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (value) SELECT value FROM TABLE_1 WHERE key <= 2`

Table_2 will now look like this:

`sub_index | value
1         | banana
1         | apple
2         | banana
3         | carrot
1         | apple
2         | banana`

In other words, every time I run the query, I want the `sub_index` field to start from 1 and increment for every record inserted by the query.

How do I implement this behaviour for `sub_index` using only SQL? (ie. no programming with PHP.)

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: I've clarified the question. I want the sub_index field to start from 1 each time I run the query.

Comment: Why store this derived data at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 set @row_nb=0;
 INSERT INTO Table_2 (`sub_index`,`value`) select (@row_nb := @row_nb +1) as `key`,`value` from Table_1 WHERE `key`< 4
```